# Format a number based on the given format

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to format a given mobile number to a given format.Number will be stored as a plain 10 digit number in the data base and to show it in the UI i need to format this number.

I am using JSTL to display this on the JSP side.I was planning to create a custom function which should accept the mobile number/phone number and the required format and will return the number in required format like

(xxx) xxx-xxx
xxx-xxx-xxx

I was trying to split given phone number based on the regExp but not very sure how to do this

```
String phoneNumber="1232345678";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\d{3}\\d{4}");
String [] s=pattern.split(phoneNumber);
```

Another way to split given string and den can use concatenation produce a desired format.

What can be the best way to achieve this

Comment: I think you should use a Matcher to match individual parts. `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html`

Comment: It might be worth taking a look a Google's libphonenumber: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: @DaveWebb:yes i already have gone through this and it really a good option, was looking if this can be done with simple java only

Answer (score 2):

You need only *one line*:

```
String output = phoneNumber.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
```

This code produces the following effect:

```
1232345678 --> (123) 234-5678
```

The moral here is:

- Use the API (rather than writing your own code)
- Don't over-complicate things (when a simple approach is available, use it)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at brute force solution:

Simply put a format in such as, "(xxx) xxx-xxxx", and the code will replace x with numbers from the phone number.

```
public static String format(String number, String format) {
    char[] arr = new char[format.length()];
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < format.length(); j++) {
        if (format.charAt(j) == 'x')
            arr[j] = number.charAt(i++);
        else
            arr[j] = format.charAt(j);
    }

    return new String(arr);
}
```